# How do you delete a file from an old commit in a GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I am logged in to GitHub and browsed a repository at a certain point in history (a few commits/pushes ago). I found a file in this old commit/push that I need to delete, but when I click on the file the delete button is disabled and displays "You must be on a branch to make or propose changes to this file" when I hover over it.

I have researched this message, but still don't understand 1) what it means and 2) how to delete this file.

How would you delete this file?

Comment: Has the file already been deleted in a more recent commit?

Comment: @Devon yes, it has.  edit: the file is still in the repo though- I can download it, view data in Raw, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of the point of a VCS, being able to see file history as they are changed.

Comment: Why do you need to delete it? Just to "tidy up", because it contains sensitive information, because it's too big, something else?

Comment: @Chris yeah it's too big and has been part of some recent commits.  I don't mind deleting the files individually, in each commit, if needed.  Just not certain how to do this.

Comment: @Chris, I was hoping to learn how to accomplish this using the GitHub web UI. As stated in the post, the delete button is visible, but is disabled.

Comment: There is no mechanism for doing this in GitHub's web UI.